# vb access subform with onclick button

Tags: vba, ms-access

Firstly, I know my problem kinda simple, but I am very new on this.
I have a form that contains button (generate_btn), subform (result_sbfrm), table (table1). The goal is, I want my subform display the result of a query after I click the button.

Here is the code I have made:

```
Private Sub generate_btn_Click()
    Dim qry As String
    qry = "select * from Table1;"
    Me.result_sbfrm.Form.RecordSource = qry
End Sub
```

It returns error 2467 "the expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist."

Debug stops at "Me.result_sbfrm.Form.RecordSource = qry"

Comment: @haraman: do you know anything about MS Access?
as the error suggest, your "result_sbfrm" doesn't exists. check whether the  subform name is correct or check if it has different name assigned than the form name..

Comment: @haraman yes the op inaccurately tagged vb.net. By looking at the procedure structure, you should have known its not vb.net sub at all^^

Comment: @krishKM it could also mean that the form is simply not open/loaded.  If the form is not open you cannot reference anything on it..... even if the form does exist.

Comment: @Fred yes, you are correct.

Comment: @Fred and krishKM thank you for your input, yes result_sbfrm does exist. I was using intellisense on it by pressing CTRL+Space and result_sbrfm was there

Comment: @Fred, so what do you mean not open/loaded? apologies for the newb question. I just simply add the subform into my form and name it as result_sbfrm. Is there a step that i have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message is telling you, you are trying to set the record source of an object that is closed so open it first.

Its a long time since I have worked with VBA or Access but something like.....

```
Private Sub generate_btn_Click()
    Dim qry As String
    qry = "select * from Table1;"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "result_sbfrm"
    Forms!result_sbfrm.RecordSource = qry 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Fred,

Comment: Thanks for your help Fred, actually this is not exactly helping my issue but I can understand the logic why the error occurs through the code you gave. I have found the exact solution, first we have to create the form that only show the query and set the source with the query we want, then we create the sub form in the main form and create the event to call that form with query that we put before.